# Does the Sony a57 have a time-lapse function?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, timelapse, sony, intervalometer

Does the [Sony a57](http://store.sony.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10551&storeId=10151&langId=-1&productId=8198552921666433223) have a built in time lapse function? If not, where can I pick up an intervalometer? Any suggestions for a specific intervalometer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked through the manual, I believe there is no time lapse function built into the A57. You should be able to find an intervalometer at any good camera shop, or online; they are fairly common.

Comment: Are there any online stores that you would suggest to go to for a good intervalometer?

Comment: Where are you in the world? Amazon usually has a fair number of photography stores selling through them.

Comment: I'm in the US so yes I will look there. I meant specific stores though, even online. That would be very helpful.

Comment: I think B&H have a good name, but I'm not sure, not being in the US. Perhaps @rfusca or jrista can make a suggestion?